# Ember.js {{render}} helper model not correctly set

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I ran in a strange issue. I have an Article template. Within the article template I call a `{{render "category/new" category}}`.

However when saving the new Category trough an action the wrong model is used. When I change it to `{{render "category/new" this}}` it uses the Article model. When I leave the model part empty it does also not work.

The **Template**:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="article">
    ((...))
    {{render "category/new" category}} // calls the popup for adding a new category
    ((...))
</script>

<!-- popups -->
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="category/new">
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>Add new category</h2>

        Name: {{input type="text" value=name}}<br />
        Image: {{view App.UploadFile name="image" file=image }}<img {{bind-attr src=image}}><br />
        Category-parent: {{input value=categoryRelation}}<br />

        <button {{action 'saveCategory'}}>Save</button>
        </div>
</script>
```

The **Router**:

```
// both routes have the render called, it uses the same template
this.resource('article', {path: '/article/:id'}); 
this.resource('article.new', {path: "/article/new"});
```

The **Model**:

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    image: DS.attr('string'),
    categoryRelation: DS.belongsTo('category')
});

App.Article = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    category: DS.hasMany('category')
)};
```

The **Controller**:

```
App.CategoryNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        saveCategory: function () {
            console.log('CategoryNewController saveCategory action'); // gets called
            console.log(this.get('model')); // the wrong one
            this.get('model').save(); // saves all categories when using {{render "category/new" category}} 
        }
    }
});
```

Please note, there is no route for Category/new because it is not needed for the {{render}} helper. See: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_specific (see table at the bottom of the page)

Comment: Seems like it should work. Can you set up a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Article, `category` is a `has-many`, so you are setting the model of `CategoryNewController` to an array of `Category` (unless you've left out a part that creates a `Category` object when the user clicks new or something.)

Comment: I begin to splutter here... :) Does this mean that I have to retrieve the data 'manually' in the `saveCategory` action? I thought it was possible to have a separated model for the `{{render}}` helper as stated in the guides. See: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-render-code-helper

Comment: You should implicit target the model on `{{render}}` tag: `{{render "category/new" App.Category}}`, but I'm not sure, that it work like you want to.